# Is there any limit on number of file name we can pass in tar

Tags: linux, tar

I am creating a tar and untar it at other location using:

```
$ tar -C sourcedir -cf - . | tar -C targetdir -xpf -
```

but it fails like this
Error I am getting is :`Argument list too long - tar`, when I am reducing the number of files I mean doing it in batches of files(like 1000 files at a time) it works.

Another point I noticed:

if file names are shorter than it works fine.

I am not sure what exactly is limiting this? please give suggestions.

Comment: Looks more like a unix than a programming question. Please also always give the complete error message you get.

Comment: Are you sure you are using that exact command and getting that exact message? Looks strange.

Comment: My guess is that the first dot was actually a `*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Argument list too long* is not an error specific to `tar`. It is an error (`E2BIG`) of the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall (given by the kernel, which has to put some limitations on `execve` to avoid spoiling memory). So your shell (which `fork`-s then `execve`-s the `/bin/tar` program) tells you that error message.

<sup>It could be difficult to increase that limit (perhaps some `sysconf`, I forgot the details). Or recompile your kernel and increase the `ARG_MAX` in its `include/uapi/linux/limits.h`.</sup>

GNU [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) accepts many interesting options (so please read the man page), in particular:

> -T, --files-from=FILE
>
> ```
>          Get names to extract or create from FILE.
> ```

So collect the file paths to be archived in some (e.g. temporary) file, then pass it with `-T` and you won't get any limitations.

However, the `tar` command has many interesting features, and you can use them to have a reasonably sized command.

See also [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and [xargs(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html). Consider also [dar](http://dar.linux.free.fr/) or [afio](http://members.chello.nl/%7Ek.holtman/afio.html) (as altenatives to `tar`) or [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

You might use GNU [cp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) as `cp -va sourcedir destdir`

Comment: is there any way we can increase the limit for the argument list?

Comment: Don't do that. Just learn to use more wisely `tar`.

Comment: sure thanks.. is this files-from and -T option also has any limitations?

Comment: Surely, limited by available resources. Nothing is infinite in this universe (except, and we are not sure, the universe itself).

Comment: In addition, even in an infinite universe, you could not see all of it. Some we *always* have limitations.